# Android Outlook Search problems

Tags: search, outlook

Outlook for Android appears incapable of searching my IMAP emails (text or even subject) except for the inbox.
Zero matches every time, when Outlook on the desktop and Windows Mail have no trouble with the same mailbox.
However new the emails, it can't find them if they are in any folder other than the inbox.
It searches all Gmail folders fine, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, what you're experiencing sounds symptomatic of the account IMAP folders not being synced to your current point-of-use device.  There should be configuration settings somewhere that allow you to choose which individual folders you want to sync from your mail server to your device.  If you're unable to find such settings, you may want to try another application that offers such fine-tuning, or possibly even check if there's any options available server-side (e.g., via browser webmail client).

Answer (score 0):

It seems this has been encountered by many users of Outlook for Android (myself included). All the research I have done indicates that this is a bug in the app (at least in recent versions). There have been multiple posts on the Microsoft community sites, such as [Outlook Android Search](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/outlook-android-search/1ba5e4a6-0070-4238-a8b8-1e39cee241fa?page=2).

It seems a workaround is to

> click on the down arrow next to the home icon (looks like a house) to the left of the search box and then hit 'all accounts' on the drop-down menu.

This only works if you have multiple accounts; I only have one account and there is no option to search all accounts.

I suspect there is an indexing problem - if anyone knows how to clear the index then re-index, please advise.

It would be great if Microsoft were to fix this issue.

My version of Outlook for Android is 4.2343.1.